# Help to come up with an efficient algorithm

Tags: algorithms

We assume the distance between two bit strings equals the number of positions in which the values of the bits in these rows are different. For example, the distance between rows and 10001 and 11011 is equal to two, and between rows and 10001 and 01010 — four. You want to split an array of strings by the maximum possible number of clusters so that the distance between rows from different clusters was not less than three.

Comment: Use an exclusive or operation and then add all the values up. It is also unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX: we want to divide the array of bit strings by the maximum possible number of parts so that the distance between lines from different parts of the have been at least three. Output format: maximum number of such parts

Comment: This sounds like a basic "dynamic programming" problem.  Just check every splitting into 2 clusters, recur on the clusters, memoizize the results for each set of parameters.  There is some ambiguity in the problem, how do you count strings that aren't the same length?  (Btw, whenever you see a problem about contiguous subarrays, it's almost always about memoization, since there are only a quadratic number of contiguous subarrays.)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm A :

> A(T[1..n],current,endCluster,next):
>   If $next=n+1$ then
>
> > if $current=endCluster$ then
> >
> > > return T[1..endCluster]+ A(T[current+1..n],1,1,2)
> >
> > else
> >
> > > return A(T[1..n],current+1,endCluster,endCluster+1)
>
> else
>
> > if d(T[current],T[next])< 3 then
> >
> > > swap T[endCluster+1] and T[next];
> > >       return A(T[1..n],current,endCluster+1,next+1)
> >
> > else return A(T[1..n],current,endCluster,next+1)

Correctness is easy to show.

The complexity is $n(n-1)/2$ comparison for the worst case.